# How to detect a phone call in Android phone with React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm building an app and I need to detect all phone calls, assuming my app is always in the background.

I've looked over `react-native-call-detection` package from
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-detection.

The question is, **how do I make the listener global**, meaning that it doesn't matter in which screen the user is or if the app is in background, how to detect incoming calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new class for the listener, than make a new class element in every screen.
For example you create a class like, phoneCallListener, this class has a constructor, and a function which starts the detection, which name would be, startDetection();
Then in every activity you create a new element, like phoneCallListener myListener = new phoneCallListener(); , then you call the method and you are read, myListener.startDetection();

Another soluton is to make only one screen with fragments, so you will have one activity which's screen can change, so there will be a global class, and a fragment class.